# How to calculate days between two dates and compare in a salesforce report?

Tags: reporting, custom-field, date, customization

How to Create a report that pulls the CDate and SDate and shows if there’s 120 days or less between the two dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a formula field for this in the object itself and use it in your report.Below link will help you do this:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm